# RxJava - replay + autoConnect + refCount

Tags: rx-java

I have this requirements:

1. an observable that preforms a network request
2. between 1-3 entities can subscribe to it, but we want only one request for that (cache of 1) (autoConnect)
3. they can subscribe after the request has already received (replay(1))
4. if all subscribers unsubscribe we should unsubscribe as well (refCount)
5. upon certain event we need to make a new request, causing the subscribers to get the new item, as well as future subscribers.

The problem is that those operators does not play nice together, once you call refCount or autoConnect you get back an observable, so you can't call the other.

I've tried something like `request().repeatWhen(redoRequest()).replay(1).autoConnect().share()`
but it will not unsubscribe properly as we do double publish/connect here.

the only way I found which I'm not sure work as desired is to make the unsubscirption manually and use the overload of autoConnect which returns the subscription.

Any ideas how I can achieve it properly?

Comment: What about just keeping `replay(1).refCount()` and dropping the `autoConnect().share()`. Would that do what you want? Otherwise, you may want to have a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare

Comment: the problem is it will not autoConnect, I will have to call to connect() in order it to work, if I call it immediately it will not be lazy as observable should be,

Comment: I will check this library

Comment: I think It does exactly what I want, but I'll have to check to more carefully